# When force pushing to already sent pull request, ugly remnants of previous commits remains in issue

Tags: git, github

I have created a pull request for some library ([Unirest](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-php/issues/27) in this case). In the commit message I have marked issue it is connected to using #number format. Then I have realised I need to change something, so I have force pushed to pull request. In the pull request, I see correctly only last version, but in the issue discussion I see also previous pull request, which is both ugly, unecessary and incorrect. Is there any way to get rid of these?

In the image, you can see the issue log, but basically only last one is relevant, commits `79c3ff5`, `8415527`, `dd8b344` do not even exists.

[image: Example of bad commits]

Comment: Commits like diamonds are forever. you say that the commits don't exist, however that's not entirely accurate. Actually the commits are simply not reachable by any current reference. They still exist as you pushed them to github. You might be able to delete your fork, re-fork, re-push, and re-pull request, but not sure if that'll work.

Comment: In case it's not obvious I should mention, do NOT delete your local repo in the process lest you delete the work you have done and want to save.

Comment: Thank you. Basically, I would like to run git gc on server side, which is not possible. Will watch the issue, as according to this, Github is running it periodically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135095/git-gc-aggressive-push-to-server so maybe it will disappear someday :D

Comment: This also might also be of interest: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data

Comment: Thanks, relevant part from your link: "...Check for cached pages after you recreate the repository, if you find any open a ticket on GitHub Support and provide links so staff can purge them from the cache..." which I dont want to do :-)