# I can still checkout any commit in deleted branches, is it permanent?

Tags: git

In a repo I'm working on, dozens of feature branches have been created, worked on, merged to master, and then deleted when done. However, I can still see every single commit in any of those branches with `git log --graph`. 
With the SHAs in the graph, I can also checkout any commit in those deleted branches.

I think it's a very good thing, but my question is, are they going to be garbage-collected sometime in the future, or are they permanent?

Comment: Those feature branches are just as much a part of the history as the other parent in the merge commit.  Most likely, you would certainly want this history present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Permanent: as long as those commits are accessible through a branch or a tag, they will remain visible.
Accessible means: you can go back from a tagged commit or a branch HEAD to those older commits, through the graph of commits: see "[Understand Git history](https://www.visualstudio.com/learn/understand-git-history/) ".

If they are not accessible, then they are visible through [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog), and garbage collected eventually (`gc.reflogExpire` is by default 90 days), or before with [`git gc`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc).

Comment: So anything visible through `git log --graph --all` is permanent (unless you rewrite history); everything else will eventually be cleaned up.

Comment: @DanielH That is the general idea, yes.

Comment: Do you know of any exceptions to that? I think it's exactly correct, but there might be an edge case I'm not thinking of.

Comment: @DanielH Not that I know of. And this is why, if you delete something, clean your repo (gc) and push a deletion... you still need to contact the remote server support to ask for a similar cleanup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47771133/6309