# How can I force GitLab to carry out a garbage collection (and permanently remove a file)

Tags: gitlab

One of our developers checked in (and pushed) a secure file.

I removed the file from their history, and did a push --force, in order to get the new history out there, which now doesn't include the file.

However, the orphaned check-in from before is still referenced in the project "Activity", and if I click on the hash then I can still see it that checkin, and the file.

Because it's no longer referenced by the master/head, I assume this orphan checkin will vanish the next time that GitLab carries out a garbage collection.  But I'd like that to happen *now*, so that the secure file is no longer accessible.

How can I force this to happen?

Answer (score 4):

Running housekeeping should solve your problem. When running housekeeping Gitlab will run a `git repack` or `git gc` (depending on the admin settings).

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/housekeeping.html for more info.

Comment: I was not ablo to find `menu/admin` page on the githab to make changes. Is it a free feature to use it?

Comment: No, this is feature available to all tiers. It is found under the repository "general settings", under the "advanced" collapsible. https://imgur.com/f4EUe8n