# Overwrite .git folder in remote

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a repo when cloned is 43GB where the src files are just 2GB. ./git/objects folder is 41GB in total.
I did some cleaning to remove the large files from history and was able to reduce the size of repository to 3.6GB in local.
Now, I want to push these changes to remote and I tried the below commands, but I'm seeing *Everything up-to-date* because there are no changes to src files.

```
git push origin --force --all
git push origin --force --tags
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

After running the above commands, When I clone the repository, it's size is 43GB.
How can i overwrite the .git folder in remote ?

The remote is hosted on bibucket.

Comment: what service hosts your remote ? github ? gitlab ? ...

Comment: for example: [github documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository) (link found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21364721/86072)) indicates that you should contact github support to ask them to run a gc action on their side. With gitlab, on self-managed repositories you will have a [housekeeping action](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/housekeeping.html#manual-trigger) -- I guess in SaaS mode it will require asking customer support. etc ...

Comment: The repository is hosted on bitbucket, Atlassian tool.

Comment: ok, search for "bitbucket git gc" or "bitbucket housekeeping", and look for how to have a gc on the server side