# GitHub: how to remove a commit that is not on any branch?

Tags: git, github

I pushed a branch to GitHub. This branch has a commit 1234567 that mentions issue #999 in its commit message. Because of this, commit 1234567 shows up on the issue #999 discussion page.

Then I decided that commit 1234567 was slightly wrong. I amended it, resulting in a new commit ab12cd3, and force-pushed the branch to GitHub. Now the issue #999 page references both commits — 1234567 and ab12cd3. If I follow the link to 1234567, I see my original commit, it’s just not on any branch now (no branch name shown).

How can I remove the original commit 1234567 from the issue #999 page?

Comment: Have you tried `git revert --no-commit <commit hash>` ?

Comment: @Shravan40 Nice answer, but I feel that this is a GitHub problem, and that maybe they should have a way to not associate dangling commits with their former branches.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You inadvertently answered my question. I googled with “dangling commit” and got http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367977

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov Glad I contributed something here.