# Delete Github tree hash from a deleted file

Tags: git, github

I had a repo with 4 branches including master on GitHub.

1.I went to each branch using the GUI and deleted one file on each branch. (it contained a ssh key).
2.I then decided to just delete the whole repo by creating another repo somewhere else and pushing to the remote.

```
mkdir repo
cd repo
git init
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
git push origin master --force
```

3.Repo is now empty with no branches(GOOD)

However, when I see the history I see this for each file I deleted:

https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY/tree/

Somehow the history got saved and files still available for anyone to see. How can I delete those tree hashes? I only have them for the files I deleted on each branch.

Comment: Can you show what you're seeing? You've obfuscated the URL so obviously we cannot see what you're seeing.

Comment: Repo is private. I'm part of an organization. So I can see my history on the organization dashboard.

Comment: GitHub as a server might show logs of older pushes, you might be better off deleting the repository on GitHub and creating a new one with the same name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a dangling commit from GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367977/how-to-remove-a-dangling-commit-from-github)