# Pruning dangling commits from GitHub fork

Tags: git, github, git-dangling

I forked a repo on GitHub.

I pushed commits (whose commit messages contain references to issues in the original repo) to my fork.

I pushed the same commits multiple times while rebasing, rewording, etc.

Thus, I've pushed different versions of the same code changes to my fork, but only the newest version is in any branch, and the older versions are all obsolete dangling commits.

I've even pruned the dangling commits from my reflog and log in my local clone.

The dangling commits, however, are still in the clone of my fork hosted on GitHub. The issues in the original repo still show every referencing commit that I pushed, even though only the latest commit is of any use.

How can I get my fork on GitHub to remove those dangling commits, and thus only show one commit in each referenced issue?

See: https://github.com/gradle/gradle-java-modules/issues/2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a dangling commit from GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367977/how-to-remove-a-dangling-commit-from-github)

Comment: The accepted answer to that appears to be wrong. The other answers are old; maybe there’s a better option nowadays…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed with GitHub support that, as of 2018-10-13, repos can only be pruned by contacting GitHub support.