# Permanently delete all history of specific branch on git

Tags: git, branch

I made a branch in my repo that includes files that aren't supposed to be checked in (they have passwords). Therefore, I went where the code is hosted (like GitHub) and deleted that branch. Then I deleted it locally.

However, when I ran `git reflog`, I see it has the branch still there. Then I saw I was still able to check it out!

My question is:

1. How can I delete the branch permanently such that there is no history of it whatsoever.
2. Can others see the branch I just deleted or just me on my local machine when I ran `git reflog`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+sensitive+files

Comment: Especially see these commands: `git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --aggressive --prune=now`

Comment: As for Github: delete the repo or contact GitHub support: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32840385/7976758