# Github history accessible by link even after deletion

Tags: git, github, commit, history

I have deleted the entire commit history of my repo by both of the following methods:

1. [how to delete all commit history in github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716658/how-to-delete-all-commit-history-in-github)
2. https://www.willandskill.se/en/deleting-your-git-commit-history-without-removing-repo-on-github-bitbucket/

Although the history is not visible on the repo page anywhere, when I try and access using an old commit link i.e. https://github.com/username/repo/blob/number/filename I am able to see the changes. The only scenario is when I change visibility of the repo when it gives 404. How do I prevent all old changes from being accessible for a public repo?

Comment: This seems to be a support question for git hub

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32840254/7976758

Answer (score 1):

You should [ask Github directly](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository#fully-removing-the-data-from-github) to trigger garbage collection.

Comment: This is the direct link to section mentioned. Looks like it's not numbered anymore https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository#fully-removing-the-data-from-github

Comment: you're wrong. GitHub doesn't run GC, you need to run GC locally to not re-push the commits removed by support though. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367977/how-to-remove-a-dangling-commit-from-github/4368673#4368673 for details